# proving that an infinite sum does not converge using radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

suppose i have to find series $a_n>0 , a_n\rightarrow 0$ but $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^na_n$ does not converge.
i chose the series $$a=\cases{\frac{1}{n}  &n is even\\ \frac{1}{n^2} &n is odd}$$
and the function  $f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n a_nx^n $ and i wanted to show that the function is not defined in $x=1$, so its enough to prove that $R<1$ radius of convergence.

$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup \sqrt[n]{(-1)^n a_n} = \max \{ \lim \sqrt[2n]{a_{2n}} ,\lim \sqrt[2n+1]{a_{2n+1}}\}$ 
 but when i try to calculate both of the limits i get 0 so $R=\infty$.
can someone please explain to me my mistake? thank you!

Comment: Both of the limits are 1. How do you get 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and you want to compute its radius of convergence using the root test, what you have to compute is $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. But, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{n^2}}=1,$$$\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(-1)^na_n|}=1$.

Comment: yes i see my problem, but when you compute the limit, shouldn you calcuate $\lim \sqrt[2n+1]{\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Comment: No, because$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\begin{cases}\sqrt[n]{\frac1n}&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\\sqrt[n]{\frac1{n^2}}&\text{ if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: i see, thank you